# How do I ship files into eclipse java plugin in order to reuse them once the plugin is deployed

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am developping an eclipse plugin that uses external jars and images. I want to ship them into my plugin jar so that when the plugin is deployed in eclipse I can use them.
My question is : Where should I put those external files in my plugin project and how should I refer to them in order to have access to them.
I have already try to reference my files like this (the folder in which my files are located is CESSAOAuthInterceptors):
    Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(Activator.PLUGIN_ID);
    Path path = new Path("CESSAOAuthInterceptors");
    URL fileURL = FileLocator.find(bundle, path, null);
But when the plugin is installed in the dropin folder of eclipse I cannot access my directory anymore.

Any suggestion on how to reference my folder in a way that I can find it wherever my plugin is installed would be really helpful, thx

Yann

Answer (score 0):

Look into JavaCore.setClasspathVariable() as a way to associate a variable name with a path value derived from the plugin's install directory (which you can query from the Activator).  You can then use that variable name in your Eclipse classpaths as a way to refer to the install directory.

This association can be made in your Activator class's startup() method.